# Selenium Webdriver can't find elements inside of iframes

Tags: java, selenium, testing, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I'm having some problems trying to run a test with selenium webdriver when an Iframe is present on the code.

There is a single Iframe inside the webpage with that I'm working:

```
<div class="bwc layout">
    <div class="bwc-frame">
        <iframe id="bwc-frame" class="bwc-frame" src="index.php?module=Campaigns&action=EditView&return_module=Campaigns&return_action=index&bwcFrame=1">
            (...)
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

But, when i try to find an element inside of that frame i get this error message:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"name"}

If i use Selenium IDE i haven't problems finding that element. It happens only with webdriver.

This is my (selenium) code:

```
WebDriver drive = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(myUrl);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

//Login in my site
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("username")));
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.name("login_button")).click();
//end of Login (everything is ok with this part, no Iframes inside)

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //For Web Loading
driver.switchTo().frame(0); //There is a single Iframe 
driver.findElement(By.id("name")); //Webdriver can't find this element
```

I tried to switch to frame in many different ways:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe.bwc-frame")));
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().frame("bwc-frame");
```

However I'm getting the same result.

I also tried an explicit wait instead of implicit wait:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("iframe.bwc-frame")));
```

and i get the same result, NoSuchElementException when i try to find the element inside of Iframe.

Please, anyone have any idea why this is failing ? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I checked there is a single Iframe present on the code, and i assured of this through  FireFinder Firefox plugin, by searching "iframe". You can look it here the result:

[image: firefinder search]

If i go to index.php (the page of my frame) and I search "iframe" again, the result is "matching elements : 0"

Also i directly went to the code of index.php.. to check if there is "id=name" on the code and yes.

So, I think I can say there is a single iframe (no nested iframes) on the code and an id=name inside.

**EDIT 2:**

Also, I saved the Iframe as a new HTML into a local path, to open it with selenium, just to try something different. If i use the locator "id=name" testing only this HTML, selenium can find the element perfectly.

Do you think the problem could be in the 3 tabs inside the iframe? Should i do some selection of the tab someway?

Comment: Sanity check: are you sure you have an element with `id="name"` under the `iframe` and there are no nested iframes?

Comment: Also, did you try to wait explicitly to wait for the element rather than the frame? As data inside frame can take time to load.

Comment: I get data out of frames all the time.  Perhaps posting the HTML would help people identify the issue.

Comment: I'm suspect of the index.php.  As alecxe asked your sure the element id="name" is in the index.php?  And that it is not in another iframe?  Your code and html works for me as expected with my own iframe src which contains an element with id="name".

Comment: The thing is if i run this test with selenium IDE everything works fine. 

you can look the test case here: http://postimg.org/image/fp6m9x7k9/

Comment: Girish Sortur, yes i tried too. I checked it with an explicit wait for the element, rather than the frame, just like this: 

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("name")));`

However i get: **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 40 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.id: name**

Comment: Are there also frames on the site beside the iframe? Also, just for my curiosity, what happens if you switch to the defaultContent before switching to the iframe?

Comment: skandigraun, no frames beside the iframe, just 3 tabs inside the frame with elements inside.

and if i switch to defaultContent, nothing different happens. same problem, can't find the elements.

Also, I saved the Iframe as a new HTML into a local path, to open it with selenium, just to try something different. If i use the locator id=name working with that HTML, selenium finds the element perfectly.